# Is there a common name for all command shell scripts?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminology

I frequently find myself needing to describe a simple Linux command that can be performed on all major shell interpreters (ksh, bash, sh), but I don't know how to indicate that. Some examples would be: `ls`, `cd`, or `cp`.

To get specific, I want to speak without referring to any shell in particular. In a SQL context, this is simple: "SQL" refers to the shared standard between all flavors (Oracle, MSSQL, etc.). SO seems to believe the term is "shell", but even it demands you use a more specific shell tag, implying that there is no workable shared functionality.

Is there a name for all the shared syntax between Unix/Linux command shells, or does it not exist at all?

Comment: `ls`,`cd`,`cp`,`mv`, etc are all referred to as "commands", but there are other terms, like "executable", and possibly "shell-built-in" (but generally not for these). These are not consider "syntax" of shells. They are cmds that accept certain arguments defined in the respective `man` page, i.e. `man ls`. If  you make an error in the args to the cmd, you'll get an error message. When working from a cmd-line, you need a mech. to "run" the command, hence the shell. The shell allows programming with `if/then`, `while/do` etc constructs and provides other syntax features. Out of room. Good luck.

Comment: `ls`, `cp`, and `mv` have nothing directly to do with the shell (apart from the fact that they're commonly invoked from the shell).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ls`, `cd`, and `cp` are all instances of what POSIX calls **[*utilities*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_433)**.

Utilities may be ***external*** (an executable file in the filesystem) or ***built-in*** (internal to the shell).

Some utilities exist both as a **[*regular* shell built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tagtcjh_18)** as well as an external utility (e.g., `test`).
Additionally, there are **[*special built-in utilities*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14)** (e.g., `.`), which are internal to the shell only.

From a broader perspective, you can call them *POSIX / [standard] Unix [command-line] utilities*.

POSIX mandates both [*what* utilities are part of the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/toc.html) <sup>Scroll down to bullet point `Utilities` on the linked page.</sup>
 (must be present on conformation systems) as well as what specific *options* they must support and behaviors they must exhibit.

Actual platforms are typically a *superset* of that - both in terms of offering nonstandard utilities and having standard utilities support additional, nonstandard options.

To refer to the **standardized shell language syntax**, you can use the term [*[POSIX] shell command language*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), though the shorthands `sh` or `/bin/sh` are frequently used, based on the fact that the default shell on Unix-like systems can only be expected to implement POSIX-mandated features (and nothing more).

---

Note that ***built-in* utilities are a shell-specific concept** (and a POSIX-compatible shell must support the options and behaviors specified in the POSIX shell-language specification).
They cannot be called (directly) when no shell is involved, such as when using `xargs`, or `find ... -exec`.

By contrast, ***external* utilities exist independently of the shell**, even though they are typically *called* from the shell.

Comment: `cd` actually can't be an external utility, as then it would do nothing.

Comment: @jwodder: Actually I've seen `/usr/bin/cd` on some systems (Solaris), but its only purpose is to indicate whether you *can* change to a specified directory. It's normally hidden by the `cd` command built into each shell.

Comment: @jwodder: Indeed, thanks for the correction - fixed.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Interesting; OSX has one too, and it's a shell script (`sh`) that calls `builtin \`echo ${0##*/} | tr \[:upper:] \[:lower:]\` ${1+"$@"}`